# How to configure Synaptics circular/chiral scrolling to make smaller circles?

Tags: synaptics, scrolling

In Windows I can use circular/Chiral scrolling by drawing very small circles (green circles) but in Ubuntu/Linux I have to make big circles to makes it work. Otherwise the page keep going up and down.

[image]

Comment: how did you configured it at all to have chiral scrolling at least somehow? i cannot find a way to enable it at all in ubuntu 19.10...

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember but I think it was on Arch or a distro based on it.

Comment: Which means it has nothing to do with Ubuntu the only distro supported on this site.

Answer (score 0):

The smaller your circle is, the faster will go the scrolling.

The thing is: the circle center is always locked to the central point of the trackpad, so you should move your finger relative to this. Otherwise, you're just moving at the same side back and forth, as the finger must go to the other side relative to the center for the scrolling direction to be kept.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, sdore.  Please take the [tour].  Also, if you agree with David's comment under the question, then this question is off-topic.  This means that the question should not be answer and should be flagged to be closed.  Please read [answer] which gives advice not only on _how_ to answer, but _when_ to answer.